# how to set layout for streambuilder and a button

Tags: containers

HI i want to ask about how to set layout for streambuilder and a container.

I have a streambuilder named streamdb,
and bellow the streambuilder i want to add, a button name buttonscan.

```
Container container = new Container(margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  child: new Row(margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      children: [streamdb,buttonscan]));
```

have tried :

```
children : <Widget>[streamdb],buttonname]
children : <Widget>[streamdb,buttonname]
children : [new Expanded(streamdb),buttonname]
```

When I compiled above code produce an error, how to build a streambuilder and a button ?

last but not least why is it so hard to create a post asking a problem in stackoverflow ?

Comment: Why do you think its difficult ?

Comment: like it has to get certain characters before we can post or contain certain words ?

Comment: In that case, it's not "very" difficult. It's rather just about reading the guidelines that automatically appear when you write your first question. And IMO, such a big and helpful community is allowed to have a few simple rules.

Comment: @ZeekHuge bro, what i mean is ive read the rules, but some rules are not too clear for me, like would it be better to explain how many characters needed to post ? or and besides Would you care to help solve the problems ?? If its me, i would PREFER to solve the problems. thank you

Answer (score 0):

just solve my own problem.
Hopefully it can help other people with same problems.

1. its better to add New Expanded() to the list builder , so it tell the apps to expand as much as necessary
2. sometimes the class could not resolve "this" method , so since dart-flutter can ignore space,its better for me to just do this :

   ```
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return new MaterialApp(
         home: new Scaffold(
             appBar: new AppBar(
               title: new Text('MY App TITLE'),
             ),
       body: new Center(
                   child: new Column(
                     children: <Widget>[
           new Expanded(child:
               new StreamBuilder()),mybutton,]))
   ```

PS : Kindly post more comment for better codes. Thanks!!